# NLog rename old file changing the original file name

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, logging, nlog

I'm working with Nlog in an Asp.net framework application in a lan enviroment.
I have 10 different clients that use the application. My goal is to have different log file, one for each client. My Nlog configuration is:

```
<target name="LogFile"
    xsi:type="File"
    fileName="D:\logs\${var:idClient}.txt"
    keepFileOpen="true"
    archiveFileName="D:\logs\Old\${var:idClient}_{#}.txt"
    archiveDateFormat="yyyyMMdd"
    archiveNumbering="Date"
    archiveEvery="Day"
    layout="${var:idClient}|${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${callsite:fileName=false:includeSourcePath=false}|${message}"/>
</targets>
```

In the Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;

        string idClient= string.Empty;
        if (context.Session == null || context.Session["ClientId"] == null ||
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Session["ClientId"].ToString()))
            idClient= "Client ID Default";
        else
            idClient= System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["ClientId"]?.ToString();

        NLog.LogManager.Configuration.Variables["idClient"] = idClient;
}
```

My problem is that the old file name doesn't have the same client id of the original log file. How can I mantain the same client id and add only the data?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Luke, what are the "old file name" and the "original log file"? Try to better explain your problem, maybe with an example in order to help community to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NLog config variables are global for the entire application. It is not a good idea to modify them for every request, unless you promise to only have a single request at a time.

Instead consider adding [NLog.Web](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Web/)-nuget-package to your project and change your filetarget to use this FileName-layout:

```xml
    <extensions>
      <add assembly="NLog.Web"/>
    </extensions>
    <targets>
      <target name="LogFile" xsi:type="File"
        fileName="D:\logs\${aspnet-session:ClientId:whenEmpty=DefaultClientId}.txt" />
    </targets>
```

See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspNetSession-layout-renderer